# Retaining the last modified date while using ChannelSftp for file transfer

Tags: jsch

I am using ChannelSftp(jsch-0.1.42.jar) to copy files from a unix server and can successfully do it but the last modified date gets overwritten by the current time.

I am using 
chanSftp.get(nextName, "C:/Test/" + nextName);

Is there any way of retaining the last modified time of the remote file on the local copy?

I have the last modified time of the remote file which i got using

attrs = lsEntry.getAttrs();

Date modDate = (Date) format.parse(attrs.getMtimeString());

Answer (score 10):

Using a `SimpleDateFormat` is of less performance. Instead one could use the methods `getMTime()` and `getATime()` directly. But they deliver a value reduced by the milliseconds.
That's why they return an `int` and not a `long` as expected in conformance to `date.getTime()`.

```
SftpATTRS attrs = lsEntry.getAttrs();
Date dateModify = new Date(attrs.getMTime() * 1000L);
Date dateAccess = new Date(attrs.getATime() * 1000L);
```

In **jsch-0.1.50** be careful of using `getAtimeString()` there is the factor `1000L` missing.

---

In **jsch-0.1.51** the `getAtimeString()` bug with the missing factor is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

This changes the last modified time of the file downloaded from the remote server,

```
String remoteFilePath = "testDir/testFile.txt";
SftpATTRS attrs = sftpChannel.lstat(remoteFilePath);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
Date modDate = (Date) format.parse(attrs.getMtimeString());
String localFilePath = "C:/temp/downloadedFile.txt";
sftpChannel.get(remoteFilePath, localFilePath);
File downloadedFile = new File(localFilePath);
downloadedFile.setLastModified(modDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

Merging the answers above to a working solution:

```
sftpChannel.get(REMOTE_FILE, LOCAL_FILE);
SftpATTRS attrs = sftpChannel.lstat(REMOTE_FILE);
Date dateModify = new Date(attrs.getMTime() * 1000L);
File downloadedFile = new File(LOCAL_FILE);
downloadedFile.setLastModified(dateModify.getTime())
```